# How to solve discrepancy between 3rd party coordinates and google map?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, mapkit

I have a set of coordinates data from 3rd party provider. However when I plot those coordinates on google maps with annotations, the annotated points are not exactly on the position they should be. For example, some points should be placed on the road, however they are placed slightly off the road.

My question is, how to solve this kind of discrepancy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Coordinates (lat and long), by themselves, do not describe a position on the Earth. You need a third piece of information, called the datum. The datum for google maps is [WGS84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). The datum establishes such things as *where* 0,0 is on the Earth's surface.

If you've received coordinates, and those coordinates are based on a different datum, then they will not plot correctly on Google Maps.

On the other hand, if the points came from any kind of mobile device (even if it is using WGS84), there are inherent inaccuracies in such measurements (thankfully generally down to < 5m for GPS these days, I believe) that mean that they will not align 100%.